# Filter a product block collection by custom attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I extended `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`'s `_getProductCollection()` previously to return 6 random products to display on the home page. This code was working fine.

```
$this->setCategoryId(40);
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($this->getCategoryId());
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
$collection->getSelect()->limit(6);
$collection->addStoreFilter();

Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
$collection->load();
```

I added a custom product attribute and updated the code to:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(4)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('cc_featured', array('eq' => true));
$collection->getSelect()->limit(6);
$collection->addStoreFilter();
```

Where `4` is my root category. However this returns no results. I debugged the SQL and the problem appears to be this condition `cat_index.is_parent=1`.

I am not sure if I am going about this right and need some guidance. I have tried answers to similar questions, at best it will find 6 products, but it is missing all the product detail (price, image, etc)

Comment: The provided code will only get you the products that are placed directly in the root directory, not all the products within its child directories.

Comment: Understood. How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you must load random products that in the children categories of cat 4, or you can get random products from all visible and in-stock product pool?

Comment: Any product which has the custom attribute `cc_featured = 1`. Regardless of category.

Comment: Please check the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As clarified by comment, this code should retrieve a site-wide product collection of 6 random enable products with filter visibility = 4 (Catalog & Search) and cc_featured = 1.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status',1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility',4)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('cc_featured',1);
$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'))->limit(6);
```

Note

- Status = 1 to not load disabled products
- Visbility = 4 to not load products are not visible individually (e.g. simple products that belong to configurable ones)
- You don't have to extend the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` for this to work, extending `Mage_Core_Block_Template` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, there's a load on your collection:

```
$collection->load();
```

But not in your updated code. I'm not sure how the rest of your module is coded, but there's an event (catalog_block_product_list_collection) that is dispatched around line 62 of the method _beforeToHtml in Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List. Mage_Review has an observer on this event in Mage_Review_Model_Observer in the method catalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtml, line 78. This observer loads the collection. After the collection is loaded, it cannot be modified. Maybe this your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled over the exact same problem:

**protected function _applyProductLimitations()** in **Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection**

```
    $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()
                    ->quoteInto('cat_index.category_id=?', $filters['category_id']);

    if (isset($filters['category_is_anchor'])) {
          $conditions[] = $this->getConnection()
          ->quoteInto('cat_index.is_parent=?', $filters['category_is_anchor']);
    }
```

and $filters['category_is_anchor'] is set in the same class.

```
public function addCategoryFilter(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category)
      {
          $this->_productLimitationFilters['category_id'] = $category->getId();
          if ($category->getIsAnchor()) {
              unset($this->_productLimitationFilters['category_is_anchor']);
          } else {
              $this->_productLimitationFilters['category_is_anchor'] = 1;
          }

          if ($this->getStoreId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract::DEFAULT_STORE_ID) {
              $this->_applyZeroStoreProductLimitations();
          } else {
              $this->_applyProductLimitations();
          }

          return $this;
      }
```

SOLUTION: Set your root category as an anchor under catalog->categories.